# Are there Windows PowerShell-like key bindings for Bash or Zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh

Honestly, after using Bash and Zsh for a long time before ever learning Windows CMD or PowerShell, PowerShell's CUA-style key bindings (ctrl+arrows to move word by word, ctrl+a to select the whole command line, ctrl+v to paste, ctrl+c to copy, etc) are simply still just more productive for me. It's the way most modern editors work.

I like Vim, but I haven't any Vim emulation to be good enough. I'd really like to have CUA bindings in Bash or Zsh (not Emacs or Vi).

Is this possible?

Comment: Man, I wish there was a Linux shell with a CUA option. After trying this in Windows CMD, I've realized how EASY this makes editing in the command line! It's the one thing I actually like about Windows CMD! In PowerShell, if nothing is selected, `ctrl+c` cancels the command line, and only does a copy when text is selected. This is POWERFUL.

Comment: I have to retract my previous statement. **Ctrl+C** is actually not handled by the shell but by the terminal, which in turn then sends a `SIGINT` to the shell. And it is in fact possible to change this to some other key binding in order to free up **Ctrl+C**. [See this answer on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314289/52652)

Comment: @trusktr to be fair, there is at least pone Linux shell with CUA binding options: PowerShell.

Comment: Hi, did you find something that match your need, can you shared with me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exists for Bash, its [`ble.sh`](https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh), which stands for Bash Line Editor.sh. It makes Ctrl + Left/Right jump entire words and Shift + Left/Right highlights characters, Ctrl + Shift + Left/Right does both, these are the standard CUA bindings. Now the highlighting it implements is different from the highlighting we get from using the mouse (this is implemented by the terminal emulator you are using), and it is this second one that is copied from on Ctrl + Shift + c. `ble.sh` does not implement any copy/paste functionality that I know of.

If you don't like that Ctrl + Shift + c is copy, then look into using a terminal emulator that allows that sort of rebinding, [`kitty`](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/conf/#clipboard), and [`terminator`](https://terminator-gtk3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/preferences.html#keybindings) are places to start. In fact, it looks like `kitty` allows you to bind Ctrl + c to `copy_or_interrupt` which sounds like exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

For `bash`, it's all documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bindable-Readline-Commands). There are default bindings, but you can change them, and you can even define macros.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with PowerShell and comfortable with the Windows key bindings I'd recommend just using PowerShell as your shell on Linux.  PowerShell is these days [widely available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-linux) across Linux distributions and can be configured to use key bindings you want with:

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -EditMode Windows
```

The default edit mode on Linux is Emacs style key bindings.  You can add the above line to `~/.config/powershell/profile.ps1` to change the setting for all new shells.